# How to enable the new optional features using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, windows-10-v20h2

In Windows 10 version 20H2 it seems that `MSPaint.exe` has become an "Optional Feature" but it's not found in the legacy optional features. It's only visible in the new `Settings` app.

Likewise, when you run `Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | Format-Table` you don't see the new optional features.

I have tried running:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "Microsoft Paint" -All -LogLevel WarningsInfo
```

and I get

> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : Feature name Microsoft Paint is unknown.

I can enable the optional feature manually through the GUI but what if I want to push paint out to a group of  computers? We need a new PowerShell command? Or Are we waiting for Microsoft to add the new optional features to the cmdlet?

Comment: Actually dism in cmd works fine here, all the PowerShell commands mentioned here are provided by dism, so why don't you just use dism in cmd? And as far as I know, PowerShell takes a short while to initialize on first execution since last shutdown, using cmd seems to be quicker...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this is technically considered a "Capability" rather than an "Optional Feature", thus the correct native PowerShell command is `Add-WindowsCapability`.

The current full command for adding the MSPaint capability is:

```
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name Microsoft.Windows.MSPaint~~~~0.0.1.0
```

Now, obviously that ends up being rather tied to the version, so you may wish to use wildcards. Unfortunately, `Add-WindowsCapability` does not appear to accept wildcards, but `Get-WindowsCapability` does:

```
Get-WindowsCapability -Online -Name Microsoft.Windows.MSPaint* | Add-WindowsCapability -Online
```

(NB: I don't know how this will react if it turns out multiple versions/packages are available at the same time.)

You can, of course, get a full list of available capabilities with just the command:

```
Get-WindowsCapability -Online
```

Or a filtered list of MSPaint-related ones:

```
Get-WindowsCapability -Online -Name *MSPaint*
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [DISM](https://ss64.com/nt/dism.html) to install (or uninstall) `mspaint.exe` in newer versions of Windows 10.

**To install Microsoft Paint** open an admin elevated command prompt or PowerShell and run:

```
DISM /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.Windows.MSPaint~~~~0.0.1.0
```

**To uninstall Microsoft Paint** open an admin elevated command prompt or PowerShell and run:

```
DISM /Online /Remove-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.Windows.MSPaint~~~~0.0.1.0
```

### Supporting Resources

- [Enable or Disable Windows Features Using DISM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/enable-or-disable-windows-features-using-dism)

  > The Deployment Image Servicing and Management (DISM) tool is a
  > command-line tool that is used to modify Windows® images. You can use
  > DISM to enable or disable Windows features directly from the command
  > prompt, or by applying an answer file to the image. You can enable or
  > disable Windows features offline on a WIM or VHD file, or online on a
  > running operating system.
  >
  > **To find available Windows features in an image**
  >
  > List all of the features available in the operating system from an admin elevated command prompt or PowerShell run:
  >
  > ```
  > Dism /online /Get-Features
  > ```
- [DISM](https://ss64.com/nt/dism.html)
- [How to Install or Uninstall Microsoft Paint (mspaint) in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/140419-install-uninstall-microsoft-paint-mspaint-windows-10-a.html)
- [Features and functionality removed in Windows 10](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/windows-10-removed-features)

  > The following features and functionalities have been removed from the
  > installed product image for Windows 10. Applications or code that
  > depend on these features won't function in the release when it was
  > removed, or in later releases.
  >
  > - **Feature:** Microsoft Paint
  > - **Details and mitigation:** This application will not be available for languages that are not on the [full localization list](https://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-10-specifications#Windows-10-localization).
  > - **Removed in version:** 1703